# Toggle disabling mouse click

Tags: autohotkey

My new laptop has an annoying always-in-the-way clickpad.

I would like it so that when I hit the F1 key, left click would be disabled. Hitting F1 again would enable it again.

It's been a really long time since I've done AutoHotKey so I know the following is part of it,

```
F12::BlockClock := not BlockClick
#If BlockClick
    LButton::return
```

but I don't remember how to make the toggle back work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F12::BlockClick := not BlockClick

#If BlockClick
{
    LButton::return
}
```

Comment: No need for the brackets, the `#if` is positional, it affects all hotkeys and hotstrings physically beneath it in the script.

Answer (score 2):

```
F12::BlockClick := not BlockClick

#If BlockClick

LButton::return

#If
```